Flutter Release exe not working on window 7 but it work on window10+,
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q6zlSlpiHCj9MRqECLMdNcf0_XBn0z_y/view?usp=sharing
I created a flutter project and make a release exe which work on window 10+ but not work on window 7
according to documentation install Visual C++ Redistributable,all required dll file still not work,
currently it show dynamic link issue.

From official doc https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows/desktop Flutter supports 64-bit version of Microsoft Windows 10 or later


According to Flutter installation documentation, the platform operating system should be on or above Windows 10
So Kindly check the flutter installation docs link mentioned below
https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows/desktop?tab=download

i'm talking about flutter release exe file not flutter setup
